# How to search for elements where specified attribute doesn't exist, in jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to find element where attribute specified by me doesn't exist. Something like:

```
Doc.select( "some_tag[attribute=""]" );
```

or something similar to that like:

```
Doc.select( "some_tag[!attribute]" );
```

As I know natively **jsoup** doesn't support *xpath*, so it is out of the question.

Maybe there is some trick to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is using the `:not` selector. Below is an example of selecting all `divs` without an `id`.

```
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377316/how-to-search-for-elements-where-specified-attribute-doesnt-exist-in-jsoup";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
//Select all divs without id
Elements divsWithoutid = doc.select("div:not([id])");
for (Element e : divsWithoutid) {
    //See ma, no id
    System.out.println("id = " + e.attr("id"));
}
```